# Showing linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let us consider the set  $C[0,1]$ of all continuous functions. How to show that $\{f_{\alpha}:\alpha\ge 0\}$, where $ f_\alpha (x)=x^{ \alpha}$ for all x is linearly independent. In case of polynomials we can do it easily by equating with zero polynomials. How to show here? Please help.

Comment: Show that for every finite subset $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ of $[0,\infty)$, 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n c_if_{\alpha_i} = 0 \iff c_1 = \cdots = c_n = 0.
$$

Comment: Here I have a problem. Since these are not polynomials how can we say that all coefficients are zeros.

Comment: Multiply by the reciprocal of the lowest power of $x$ involved in the sum. Then take the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ of the sum to conclude that the coefficient of the lowest power must be $0$. With that term eliminated, do the same again.